# Malformed reference element occurs sporadically

Tags: c#, signedxml

I'm trying to verify the signature of an xml, I'm experiencing Malformed reference element sporadically. When I tried debugging more closely I looked at the failed XML's the getidelement is returning null for those which are failing. All the signed XML's are generated from a single server and the other server verifies the signature. Could somebody why is it failing for a few of the XML's.

Thanks,
Bhaskar.

Comment: Need to see some sample code and XML samples but...is the request for XML the same each time you call or _should_ the results be different when you are seeing the error? Perhaps this is a parser/encoding issue for some of the XML data?

Comment: You can validate an xml; file in VS.  From menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Then paste xml into view.  Errors will show in the Error List like any compiler error.  XML files are UTF-8.  I sometimes don't see error in VS because the encoding is wrong when the files are read in the c# application.